# XMonad crops dialog windows and their buttons - how to fix this?

Tags: xmonad

For example, when I try to download something, I get the following:

- the top of a dialog window:
  [image]
- the bottom where the buttons are cropped:
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

[The xmonad tour](https://xmonad.org/tour.html) had the answer all along; highlighting the relevant parts:

> #### Floating clients
>
> xmonad supports floating windows. Certain windows
> (such as transients) will be placed in a floating layer in front of
> all the tiled windows. Additionally, you can move a window to or from
> the floating layer on demand.
>
> - To float a window (or move an already-floating window), click and drag it with the <kbd>mod</kbd>-**button1** held down.
> - To flatten the window back down to the tiling layer use <kbd>mod</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>.
> - Floating windows can be resized by dragging the window with <kbd>mod</kbd>-**button3**, and
> - a floating window can be brought to the top with <kbd>mod</kbd>-**button2**.

As it turns out, this wasn't an issue at all, and I just didn't realize that dialog windows will be opened as floating ones; so the "fix" is to use <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to flatten them.

> The <kbd>mod</kbd> button for xmonad is the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key by default.

---

#### Side note

The **button** notations above refer to the mouse buttons numbered from left to right (by default). So

- **button1** is the left click
- **button2** is the middle click
- **button3** is the right click